# Efficiently recognize in which axis quarter is a given angle Angle

Tags: c++, math, mathematical-optimization

I would like to recognize in what axis quarter is a given angle
In the Most efficient way

Quarter 1:
Alpha > 0 && Alpha <= 90 (degrees)

Quarter 2:
Alpha > 90 && Alpha <= 180 (degrees)

Quarter 3:
Alpha > 180 && Alpha <= 270 (degrees)

Quarter 4:
Alpha > 270 && Alpha <= 360 (degrees)

C++ Code

```
FORCEINLINE uint8 MapAngleToQuarter(float angle)
{
    angle = (int)angle % 360;
    float answer = 0;

    if(angle > 0 && angle <= 90)
    {
        answer = 1;
    }
    else if(angle > 90 && angle <= 180)
    {
        answer = 2;
    }
    else if(angle > 180 && angle <= 270)
    {
        answer = 3;
    }
    else if(angle > 270 && angle <= 360)
    {
        answer = 4;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

My question: Is there a better (more efficient) way to do the above task ?

Comment: `alpha / 90 + 1`  assuming alpha is an integer type if not just truncate as appropriate.

Comment: What result if `Alpha < 0` or ``Alpha > 360`?

Comment: @RichardCritten  With `int Alpha`, `(Alpha - 1)/90 + 1`.

Comment: @chux my fingers faster than my brain have a +1

Comment: @chux I added some code - basically i thought of making alpha = alpha % 360; not sure how good it is... (But I actually don't care about a precision loss)

Comment: Watch your boundary cases.  For example, should 90 be in Quarter 1 or Quarter 2?

Comment: so `0` is in quadrant 1, but `360` is in quadrant 4? Do you work for PSION?

Comment: @M.M you are right, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the angle in the (0...360] range

```
FORCEINLINE uint8 MapAngleToQuarter(float angle) {
  int a = (int) angle;
  return (a - 1)/90 + 1;
}
```

Comment: @ColdSteel FYI: `return (a + 89)/90;` is another way, but semlls of micro-optimization.

Comment: Took this return '(a + 89)/90;' Solution (less operations)